# Jquery Draw Flowchart

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

I am looking for an way to draw a flowchart with jquery and then have the output saved as xml or similar so that I can create a dynamic workflow engine. I found a few purchase flowcharts but they just save the output as html or an image. Any advice on going about creating this would be appreciated.

I am also looking at creating the control from the ground up but was would not want to recreate the wheel if someone already knew of something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pop over and take a look at raphael, which is a Javascript graphing library.

http://raphaeljs.com/

I believe this is the example you are looking for:

http://raphaeljs.com/graffle.html

Answer (score 0):

I think that it is better solution:

http://jsplumbtoolkit.com/jquery/demo.html

Answer (score 0):

I have been using the [JQuery Flowchart](http://sebastien.drouyer.com/jquery.flowchart-demo/). It is very simple to use